# Swipe image gallery Flash AS3 - Application

Tags: windows, flash, actionscript-3, image-gallery

Want to make an Image gallery that responds to a swipe gesture. Found some tutorials but they were a bit vague. Someone an idea where I can find some good ones?

Does also anyone know how to test this on a windows pc? I do not have a certificate (I know that there are some illegal cert. on the internet), just want it to test it on a simulator? Know one that works allmost perfectly?

Please help me get some good sources...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=145

Comment: Are you making this into a handheld app?  What is the goal device?

Comment: @iND The goal device is an iPhone. But I must say, it's for a newbie as me pretty difficult to make. Sooo many things I will have to learn.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good tutorial on [Republic of code](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3swipegesture/)

It is my understanding that a "swipe" is essentially a mouse drag done a specific way. I would think you could test it simply by using your mouse.

I would stick with Adobe's swipe guesture API on this one. but, As a second less cool option, before the touch screen events were available I implemented "swipe" by using mouseDown {record coordinates} then mouseUp {if new coorindates considerably different it's a swipe}. There were of course things to work through but it worked for me.

Comment: does it work like a native app for the iPhone? Did you test that or do you know that?

Comment: My target devices were 20-25 inch Windows All-In-One touch screen computers. I don't see why swipe gestures or my manual solution wouldn't work with iOS, I've never tested for iOS though. Still, I would use the built in swipe gestures over my solution.

Comment: Both this answer and the first comment (under the question itself) are good answers, and essentially the same.  I would recommend simultaneously adding mouse interaction to control the movement, since you would be able to use it in a web browser as a Flash file.  Also, remember that there are a few cases where mouse events are automatically translated to touch events, so you do not have to actually write two sets of code . . . though I don't think that applies to gestures (I forget!).